# Minimum of the functional $F[f]=\int_0^1 f'(x)^2dx-\log \left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have to find a minimum, if exists, for the functional
$$F[f]=\int_0^1 f'(x)^2dx-\log \left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
On the space
$$f\in H^1((0,1)):\ f\ge 0,\ \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx=1$$
(this may not be the best choice, if you have a better ides for the functional space be free to suggest).

At first I tried with the Euler-Lagragne equation with the lagrange multipliers, which gave me the differential equation
$$2f''(x)=\lambda+\frac{\delta_{1/2}(x)}{f(1/2)}\qquad \text{ in } D'((0,1))$$
with Neumann boundary conditions:
$$f'(0)=0,\qquad f'(1)=0$$
Is there a way to solve it (analitically or numerically)?
Does it make sense that the solution becomes a kind of **spline**?

Comment: What's $v$ in $\int_0^1 f'(v)dx$?

Comment: It's a typo, my fault

Comment: Well, then yes, the solution becomes a spline. Why not?

Comment: Ok, it is great to have something that does not contradict intuition ahahah.

Comment: What about solvability?

Answer (score 1):

This $\delta$ on the rhs can be translated to a jump in $f'$ at $1/2$:
$$
f'(x) = f'(0)+ \int_0^x f''(t) =  \lambda x+ 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<1/2\\
\frac1{f(1/2)} & \text{ if } x > 1/2.
\end{cases}
$$
This can be made rigorous using smooth test function and integration by parts on $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$.

Then $f$ is a quadratic polynomial on $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$, continuous, with prescribed jump of $f'$ at $1/2$. This should make it possible to solve for $f$.